# I have a firebase development and production. how do I firebase.initializeApp the app with apply target?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase development and production. how do I firebase.initializeApp the app with apply target for development and production?

```
const firebaseConfigDev  = {}

const firebaseConfigProd = {}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfigDev || firebaseConfigProd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [environment variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) for this.

Set an environment variable like `firebase functions:config:set app.environment="dev"` after selecting your project and you can add in your functions file a conditional to choose between the different environemnts:

`const serviceAccount = functions.config().app.environment === 'dev' ? 'credentials-dev.json' : 'credentials-prod.json';`

After that, you can use the file depending on the project like so:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://nwDEV.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Comment: can i set this on hosting? I know it can be set on functions.

Comment: Could you be more specific by adding it to hosting what do you mean?

Comment: i see that you use this on cloub functions, can it be used on --only hosting

Comment: No, you cannot only use this on hosting unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your development app locally, then luckily, in react (nextjs) apps, you have access to process.env.NODE_ENV variable which holds the dev/prod environment value.

You can access process.env.NODE_ENV from anywhere in your app and use it accordingly:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
  // initialize dev app
} else {
  // initialize prod app
}
```

Comment: If you are also hosting a demo development app, then you can first link your apps to your domains (https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9325939?hl=en) and use the sdk auto configuration which will automatically initialize your app based on the domain. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#sdk_auto-configuration

Comment: Here is how to better set it up in a node peoject using firebase-tools https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/easier-configuration-for-firebase-on-web.html